# Is it proper to set System property after Spring Boot application has started?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

Since every property gets set into a JVM Instance for every application, what behavior will happen once my application has set all it beans and started running at my server for below:

Will System.setProperty(String key,String value) get reflected with new changes at runtime by changing the previous key in that particular JVM Instance or new instance gets created?

Also I noticed a different exception in a constructor where i tried to setProperty just before it.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to _set_ system properties from within your own code at all.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-can you please be more explanatory and will it be fine if i create a  separate configuration bean for the System property with Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE to create it first before any other bean ,so that my other beans don't have to worry about it

Answer (score 0):

I made some tests and the results are:

If you use properties in constructors of your beans, old beans will not change after property change. Therefore changes will not affect beans with default `Scope`. If you have beans with i.e. @RequestScope, each time new request is received, new Bean with new value is created.

```
@RestController
@RequestScope
public class Controller {

    private String testValue;

    @Autowired
    public Controller(@Value("${pl.bier.test}") String testValue) {
        this.testValue = testValue;
    }

    @GetMapping("/foo")
    public FooModel fooEndpoint() {
        System.setProperty("pl.bier.test", testValue + "bar");
        return new FooModel(testValue);
    }

}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class FooModel {

    private String value;

}
```

When accessing /foo endpoint you get different responses each time (one more "hey" each time)

If you remove @RequestScope, you allways get the same answer.